# Simulating ajax request with python using requests lib

Tags: python, request

Why does `request` not download a response for this webpage?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests

headers={ 'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
     'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0',
     'Referer' : 'http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football',
    }

payload={'N': '4294966750',
     'facetCount_156%23327': '12',
     'facetCount_157%23325': '8',
     'form-trigger':'moreId',
     'moreId':'156%23327',
     'pageId':'p_football_home_page',
     'pageType':'EventClass',
     'type':'ajaxrequest'
     }

url='http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/view/EventDetailPageComponentController'

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

These are the parameters of the `POST` that I see in Firebug, and there the response received back contains a list (of football leagues), yet when I run my python script like this I get nothing.

(you can see the request in Firefox by clicking the `See All` in the competitions section of the left hand nav bar of [link](http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football) and looking at the XHR in Firebug. The Firebug response shows the HTML body as expected.)

Anyone any ideas? Will my handling of the `%` symbols in the payload be causing any trouble at all?

**EDIT: Attempt using session**

```
from requests import Request, Session

#turn post string into dict: 
def parsePOSTstring(POSTstr):
    paramList = POSTstr.split('&')
    paramDict = dict([param.split('=') for param in paramList])
    return paramDict

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0',
     'Referer' : 'http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football'
    }

#prep the data (POSTstr copied from Firebug raw source)
POSTstr = "moreId=156%23327&facetCount_156%23327=12&event=&N=4294966750&pageType=EventClass&
          pageId=p_football_home_page&type=ajaxrequest&eventIDNav=&removedSelectionNav=&
          currentSelectedId=&form-trigger=moreId"
payload = parsePOSTstring(POSTstr)

#end url
url='http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/view/EventDetailPageComponentController'

#start a session to manage cookies, and visit football page first so referer agrees
s = Session()
s.get('http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football')
#now visit disired url with headers/data
r = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

#print output
print r.text #this is empty
```

**Working curl**

```
curl 'http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/view/EventDetailPageComponentController'
-H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=DE93158F07E02DD3CC1CC32B1AA24A9E.ecomprodsw015;
    geoCode=FRA; 
    FLAGS=en|en|uk|default|ODDS|0|GBP;
    ECOM_BETA_SPORTS=1;
    PLAYED=4%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0'
-H 'Referer: http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football'
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) 
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'  
--data 'facetCount_157%23325=8&moreId=156%23327&
        facetCount_156%23327=12&event=&
        N=4294966750&
        pageType=EventClass&pageId=p_football_home_page&
        type=ajaxrequest&eventIDNav=&
        removedSelectionNav=&currentSelectedId=&
        form-trigger=moreId' --compressed
```

Yet this curl works.

Comment: You first need to visit `http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football` (instead of the homepage). *Then* it seems to work. You don't need any other headers aside from `Referer` and `User-Agent`.

Comment: @Blender I updated my answer with the minimal header you suggested, and also using a requests session to manage cookies and visit the `football` homepage first because making the ajax request, but I'm still getting an empty `r.text`, does this code run for you?

Comment: It works if you properly decode the percent-encoded characters (i.e. change `%23` to `#` before decoding it, or fix `parsePOSTstring`). I wasn't seeing the problem because I used a dictionary the whole time.

Comment: @Blender you can use unquote from urllib.parse to fix that
```import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote('facetCount_157%23325')```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's the smallest working example that I can come up with:

```
from requests import Session

session = Session()

# HEAD requests ask for *just* the headers, which is all you need to grab the
# session cookie
session.head('http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football')

response = session.post(
    url='http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/view/EventDetailPageComponentController',
    data={
        'N': '4294966750',
        'form-trigger': 'moreId',
        'moreId': '156#327',
        'pageType': 'EventClass'
    },
    headers={
        'Referer': 'http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/football'
    }
)

print response.text
```

You just weren't decoding the percent-encoded POST data properly, so `#` was being represented as `%23` in the actual POST data (e.g. `156%23327` should've been `156#327`).

Comment: Ah, many thanks. It is frustrating that is was the percent-encoding after all. So in cURL you can leave percent-encoding like `156%23327` but in python requests, you need the actual symbol rather than the encoded symbol...

Comment: @fpghost: In cURL, you send POST *data*. Requests serializes the dictionary into the same format. I think you can also pass a string instead of a dictionary and Requests will send it as-is.