# python requests 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' didn't return right contents

Tags: python, request, form-data

Hellow, everyone. I'm trying to scrawl some scientific data from a website but I'm still outside of the door. I'd tried a lot according to the online method.

Following a book for 'ajax request' and visiting some posts like [questions/22183899](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183899/simulating-ajax-request-with-python-using-requests-lib), there is no progress.

My code is as follows:

```py
# data to diliver
FORM_DATA = 'draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=species&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=pos&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=strand&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=ctype&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=host&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=score&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=nspe&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=ntis&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=nsam&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=tis&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=len&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=tlen&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bdata%5D=algo&columns%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=50&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&species=human'
form_data = FORM_DATA.replace("%5B", "[").replace("%5D", "]")
def parsePOSTstring(POSTstr):
    paramList = POSTstr.split('&')
    paramDict = dict([param.split('=') for param in paramList])
    return paramDict
form_data2 = parsePOSTstring(form_data)

# requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
base_url = "http://159.226.67.237:8080/new/browse.php"
headers = {
    'Host': '159.226.67.237:8080',
    'Referer': 'http://159.226.67.237:8080/new/browse.php',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
```

I had tried methods `requests.get` and `requests.post`, and used different values 'FORM_DATA', 'form_data' and 'form_data2' as param `data`.

```py
response = requests.get(url = base_url, data = FORM_DATA, headers = headers)
print(response.text)
```

But I got a html with ajax but without data dilivered.

What I wanted is the table in the website [circAtlas](http://159.226.67.237:8080/new/browse.php) including tables from home page and other pages.

Website show(picture seems not display, but click [this](https://github.com/gnilihzeux/circRNA/blob/master/temp/circAtlas.jpg)):

[image: circAtlas]

Comment: You absolutely definitely shouldn't be trying to parse the form data manually like that. Where does that original `FORM_DATA` string come from in the first place? Wheree are you using `form_data` and `form_data2`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman By through right-clicking 'chrome source check' and monitoring the item 'XHR' of the tab 'Network' on [circAtlas](http://159.226.67.237:8080/new/browse.php), -formdata- shows in the 'Headers'. As for `form_data` and `form_data2` were used as param of `requests.get(data = form_data, ...)`.