# Parsing json data fails, not sure why

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215705/scrapy-beautifulsoup-simulating-clicking-a-button-in-order-to-load-a-section-o), I got the code to make an ajax request here:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'authority': 'services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.6',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"fields":["issueSymbolIdentifier","issuerName","isCallable","productSubTypeCode","couponRate","maturityDate","industryGroup","moodysRating","standardAndPoorsRating","lastSalePrice","lastSaleYield"],"dateRangeFilters":[],"domainFilters":[],"compareFilters":[],"multiFieldMatchFilters":[{"fuzzy":false,"searchValue":"gme","synonym":true,"fields":[{"name":"issuerName","boost":1}]}],"orFilters":[],"aggregationFilter":null,"sortFields":["+issuerName"],"limit":50,"offset":0,"delimiter":null,"quoteValues":false}'

response = requests.post('https://services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org/public/reporting/v2/data/group/FixedIncomeMarket/name/CorporateAndAgencySecurities',
                         headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.status_code)
```

The cookie an CSRF code has been removed.

The data that I want is buried in the json response. However, any attempt to convert the json to a DataFrame or just a regular dictionary has failed.

```
data = json.dumps(response.json()['returnBody']['data'], indent=4)

print(data.replace('\\n', '').replace('\\', ''))
# print(pd.read_json(data.replace('\\n', '').replace('\\', '')))
```

gives

```
"[{"isCallable":"Y","couponRate":null,"issueSymbolIdentifier":"NTEB5563784","issuerName":"NTE MOBILITY PARTNERS SEGMENTS 3 LLC","maturityDate":"2028-06-30","productSubTypeCode":"CORP","moodysRating":"Baa2","standardAndPoorsRating":null,"lastSaleYield":null,"industryGroup":null,"lastSalePrice":null},{"isCallable":"Y","couponRate":null,"issueSymbolIdentifier":"NTEB5563785","issuerName":"NTE MOBILITY PARTNERS SEGMENTS 3 LLC","maturityDate":"2028-06-30","productSubTypeCode":"CORP","moodysRating":"Baa2","standardAndPoorsRating":null,"lastSaleYield":null,"industryGroup":null,"lastSalePrice":100},{"isCallable":"Y","couponRate":null,"issueSymbolIdentifier":"NTEB5563786","issuerName":"NTE MOBILITY PARTNERS SEGMENTS 3 LLC","maturityDate":"2028-06-30","productSubTypeCode":"CORP","moodysRating":"Baa2","standardAndPoorsRating":null,"lastSaleYield":null,"industryGroup":null,"lastSalePrice":100}]"
```

I replaced the /n and //s to make the data readable by pandas. However, it still fails reading the json with `ValueError: Trailing data`. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to use `json.loads` on the final `data` to see if it produces an error message (which may be more helpful).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\InvestmentHunter\test.py", line 30, in <module>
    data = json.loads(data.replace('\\n', '').replace('\\', ''))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)   So an error with the "?

Comment: I am guessing the first and last quotes should be replaced with 's maybe?

Comment: Copy in file and load from file using `json.load()` not `json.loads()`. I do not have any issue while loading it this way.

Comment: I guess the quotes at beginning and end shouldn't be there at all.