# How do I find the XSFR token on a page? Is it possible that it could be dynamically generated such that I can not retrieve it?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to retrieve data from a website into json then a DataFrame. I am trying to submit the XSFR token with my request like seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567507/passing-csrftoken-with-python-requests). My issue is that it seems there is no hidden input field containing the XSFR token. I had to hard code a XSFR token taken from following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215705/scrapy-beautifulsoup-simulating-clicking-a-button-in-order-to-load-a-section-o). Those tokens expire so I would like to find a way to get the XSRF token and submit it with my request. However, my request's header and cookies do not show me getting the token. Is it possible the token is being generated with JavaScript dynamically such that I can not retrieve it? Am I missing something?

My code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
session = requests.Session()
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
response = session.get('https://www.finra.org/finra-data/fixed-income/corp-and-agency')
print("Cookies: ", session.cookies) # Nothing with the token
print("Param: ", session.params)    # Nothing with the token
print("Header: ", session.params)   # Nothing with the token



get_token_response = requests.get('https://www.finra.org/finra-data/fixed-income/corp-and-agency')
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_token_response.text)
print(get_token_response.headers)  # Nothing with the token
print(get_token_response.cookies)  # Nothing with the token
print(soup.findAll('input')        # Nothing with the token

# Hard Coded
headers = {
    'authority': 'services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie':'XSRF-TOKEN=578706e6-5dfa-4beb-b887-60b42da068be;',
    'origin': 'https://www.finra.org',
    'referer': 'https://www.finra.org/',
    'x-xsrf-token': '578706e6-5dfa-4beb-b887-60b42da068be',
}


data = ('{"fields":["issueSymbolIdentifier","issuerName","isCallable","productSubTypeCode",'
        '"couponRate","maturityDate","industryGroup","moodysRating",'
        '"standardAndPoorsRating","lastSalePrice","lastSaleYield"],'
        '"dateRangeFilters":[],"domainFilters":[],"compareFilters":[],'
        '"multiFieldMatchFilters":[{"fuzzy":false,"searchValue":"gme","synonym":true,"fields":'
        '[{"name":"issuerName","boost":1}]}],"orFilters":[],"aggregationFilter":null,'
        '"sortFields":["+issuerName"],"limit":50,"offset":0,"delimiter":null,"quoteValues":false}')

response = requests.post('https://services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org/public/reporting/v2/data/group/FixedIncomeMarket/name/CorporateAndAgencySecurities',
                         headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.status_code)
data = json.dumps(response.json()['returnBody']['data'], indent=4)
data = list(data.replace('\\n', '').replace('\\', ''))
data = ''.join(data[1:-1])
df = pd.read_json(data)
```

Comment: There's a `__cfruid` in the cookies.  Is that not it?

Comment: It does not appear to be the same format but it does work hard coding the xsrf token to be it. Odd.